# Is it possible to somehow cast or convert a WindowsIdentity type to PSCredential type?

Tags: powershell, windows-identity

Context: working in PowerShell, need PSCredential object, have an object of WindowsIdentity type.

Say you obtain WindowsIdentity type using:

"[Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()"

You need PSCredential object to make a network call, e.g., Invoke-RestMethod.

Instead of calling the usual Get-Credential and prompting the user for username and pw, can we actually use the current security context to create a credential object? e.g, can we cast the WindowsIdentity object into the PSCredential (if not directly - then through a sequence of steps?).

If not then any other ideas about creating a PSCredential object from current security context (without specifying username or password - or storing encrypted username and pw as that would also require updating as the passwords change)?

Similar questions have probably been asked before but I could not find an approach of trying to convert WindowsIdentity into PSCredential type - or any definitive answer on why this might be prevented by design. If this is not fundamentally possible - what might be the reason for not supporting it? Do you see any plausible workaround? 
(I tried to add a tag: PSCredential but this tag does not already exist and I do not have enough reputation to create it: I would like to add that tag: perhaps someone from the community can add it. Thanks)

Answer (score 3):

I am sure others will have their take on this, but here are a few things as I understand them that would make this a real challenge and not prudent as a operational deal.

***[Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent(),*** gives you information about your authenticated identity on the network. ***It does not contain any info about the user password***

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx),

which is needed by ***System.Management.Automation.PSCredential***

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0).

Remember, the goal of GetNetworkCredential

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential.getnetworkcredential?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#System_Management_Automation_PSCredential_GetNetworkCredential)

(which of course is a method System.Management.Automation.PSCredential), is to breakdown your user name into separate Domain and UserName strings and hands you the credential password in clear text.

For network, client access, PSCredential will not work without a valid password being provided. Of course, if you personally entered the information, you and only you can reverse it, not some remote person or service.

Think about it for a moment. Can you imagine the risk ramifications of being able to do this unabated?

Being able to just pull, dynamically, all the auth entropy of the current logged on user. This would be an instant ESP (impersonation / escalation of privilege) problem. Password obfuscation, length, complexity, with an approach like this would be meaningless. Think Pth (Pass the Hash -like attacks) situations without ever needing toe grab the hash.

Imagine, firing off a remote session to any remote host (regardless of who is logged on to it), leveraging what you state here, thus impersonating (with all their rights and privileges) the user to do very nefarious things or even just mean things (changing their passwords, desktop settings, ADDS attributes, say if they are allowed to change there Picture, phone number, maiden name, etc. all being recorded in the audit logs as if that user did it). You could log into their personal human resource files, passing the cred object to the HR website, etc. I am sure that is not your intent (at least I hope not), but still.

All that being said, if you are after user impersonation, then there are resources that present approaches on how to do this. Yet, as you look at the code to do it, it's more involved than just what you are asking for in the MS PowerShell Gallery, but even it expects you to pass it a real cred object not a WI object.

Reaching out across a network requires a full identity, user and password. Every time to try and touch a resource you have not yet touched, or who has not in a long while, you KDC (domain controller) will be engaged and without full creds the KDC Kerb TGT will fail.

***Update***

shivesh suman

As for ---

> Thanks. Regarding: "Yet, as you look at the code to do it, it's more
>   involved than just what you are asking for ..." -  Would it be
>   possible for you to point me to some of the code that you are
>   referring to in your comment?

Here is the code I was referring to.

> Impersonate a User
>
> New-ImpersonateUser uses the LogonUser method from the advapi32.dll to
>   get a token that can then be used to call the
>   WindowsIdentity.Impersonate method in order to impersonate another
>   user without logging off from the current session.  You can pass it
>   either a PSCredential or each field separately.  Once impersonation is
>   done, it is highly recommended that Remove-ImpersonateUser (a function
>   added to the global scope at runtime) be called to revert back to the
>   original user.
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Impersonate-a-User-9bfeff82

Comment: Thanks. Regarding: "Yet, as you look at the code to do it, it's more involved than just what you are asking for ..." - Would it be possible for you to point me to some of the code that you are referring to in your comment? Is that something we can do in .Net? In PowerShell we seem to have access to all that can be done in .Net (of course I am really in a position to make such a sweeping statement - we see .Net framework being accessed directly in PowerShell routinely - in fact I am using Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity in my example.)